# Can I perform a search (of a field-html,) when using rest API SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have a field column to be specific a body column .Would I be able to build a query to filter to do a search on text?
E.g in SQL  using a "like" clause
I'd imagine using a contain in rest but it doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not with the Lists API. The `substringof` filter operator doesn't work on fields of type Note. You can do it on a text field, however. Or you can use the search API.